# How to create await-able object in python with specific methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

There is aiohttp based server that looks like:

```
import aiohttp
routes = web.RouteTableDef()
@routes.post('/route1')
async def route1(request):
    req_json = await request.json()
    step1 = func1(req_json)
    step2 = func2(step1)
    return web.Response(body=step2, status=200)
```

I want to test that server locally without running whole server, in particular step1 and step2 functions in route1.

So I do:

```
import asyncio
from myserver import route1
json_request = {"some": "data"}
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(route1(json_request))
```

Problem is, I have to replace `req_json = await request.json()` with `req_json = request` when run local tests.
How to create awaitable variable with .json() method to use instead of `json_request` dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this line to work: `await request.json()`, you don't actually need the `request` object to be awaitable. It can be a normal object with a `.json()` attribute which *"is"* an awaitable object. A coroutine would be a reasonable choice.

Like this:

```py
import asyncio
from myserver import route1

class CustomRequest:
    def __init__(self, data: dict) -> None:
        self.data = data

    async def json(self) -> dict:
        return self.data
        
json_request = {"some": "data"}
request_object = CustomRequest(json_request)
asyncio.run(route1(request_object))
```